# how to convert string array into integer array,ascending,descending,bubble,inputarea,outputarea

Tags: java, arrays, swing, events, jframe

The goal of this program is by asking the user to type any numbers in the input area field then he/she will choose any of the three buttons(ascending,descending or bubble).
then the product will output on the output area field.

Now my problem area 1.So I will ask the user to type numbers like this(1,2,3,4,5) with comma then i use split method to neglated comma but it is always string values how can i convert those values into int.2.how can I contain those values so that i can use it afterwards like putting those values on those three buttons to use to ascending,descending and bubble sort.3.after the user pick those three buttons how can I transform those those int values into string values so that I can output it properly on my outputtextfield.

I'm sorry for my grammar. I am new I tried my best to find those answer by searching on google and other forum site but no luck.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JavaGui205 extends JPanel
{

    final JTextField inputarea,outputarea;
    final JButton asc,desc,bubble;
    int getsd;

  JavaGui205()
  {

      //initialize textfield and buttons
      inputarea=new JTextField("Inputarea",20);
      outputarea=new JTextField("Outputarea",20);
      asc=new JButton("Ascending");
      desc=new JButton("Descending");
      bubble=new JButton("BubbleSort");

      //adding function on fields
      inputarea.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {             
                  if(e.getSource()==inputarea)
            {
                String sd=inputarea.getText();
                String[] inputArray=sd.split(",\\s*");                              
            }

          }
      });

      //ascending function
      asc.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {

          }
      });

      //adding to frame
      add(inputarea);
      add(asc);
      add(desc);
      add(bubble);
      add(outputarea);
  }

  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("WTF");
      frame.add(new JavaGui205());
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setSize(300,150);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to convert string array into integer

If that is your question then what is the point of the rest of the description of the problem? It is not relevant how you get the data to populate the String Array. All that is relevant is that you have an Array of Strings that represents numbers.

So learn to simplify the problem and don't make your question so confusing.

You need to convert each String to an Integer and you can use the `Integer.parseInt(...)` method to do this. Something like:

```
String[] values = ...
int[] numbers = new int[values.length];

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
    numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt( values[i] );
}
```

When you simplify the question then you can simplify the answer because you only concentrate on one thing, not the entire application.

Comment: im sorry for the too many problems.I will remind what you said next time i post my next problem. :D

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Integer.parseInt(x) method:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String) . This will convert the String into an integer type for you.

Keep in mind that if the given string is not a valid integer it will throw a NumberFormatException which is an unchecked exception so you need to remember to catch it explicitly and deal with it in an appropriate way for your app.

Comment: but sir can a string array convert to int array i tried to convert string to int it works but array its not

Comment: Integer.parseInt will just convert an individual element of the array. To convert the whole array you can use something like:   

Integer[] out = Arrays.asList(in)
        .stream()
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .toArray(Integer[]::new);

Which will give you an Integer[]. If you _really_ need an int[] you can convert it with Guava's Ints.toArray(Arrays.asList(in)) or otherwise just do it the "old fashioned" way iterating over the loop.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a string array into an int array you can use the following code.

```
int c = 0;
int[] fromStringArray = new int[inputArray.length];
for(String i:inputArray)
{
    String parseMe = i;
    try
    {
        int b = Integer.parseInt(parseMe);
        fromStringArray[c] = b;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("There was a problem changing a value");
    }
    c++;
}
```